# How to insert scraping data to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i am fetching data from other websites can any one tell me how to insert fetch data to mysql database

Below code i am using to fetch results coming

```
require_once('config.php');
    //Connect to mysql server
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if(!$link) {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select database
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
if(!$db) {
    die("Unable to select database");
}

$urls = $_POST["urls"];
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$useragent = 'Googlebot/2.1 (http://www.googlebot.com/bot.html)';

foreach ($urls as $url) 
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent); 
    $str = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $html= str_get_html($str);
    foreach($html->find('span.price') as $e)
        echo  $e->innertext . '<br>';
}

//Create INSERT query
$qry = "INSERT INTO scrapdata(price) VALUES('$e')";
$result = @mysql_query($qry);

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
    echo ("Added Success");
}else {
    echo ("Not Added");
}
```

Comment: Give us moe detail. What is the structure of the table you intend to put the data into? What have you tried thus far?

Comment: You could start by reading up on [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) or by using a framework.

Comment: You are not GoogleBot. Do not pretend to be it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO scrapdata(price) VALUES('$e->innertext')";
```

or replace the `innertext` with the required value.

Comment: Hi, Abdul it is working fine now data inserting but  foreach($html->find('span.price') as $e) error coming as Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\test\curll.php on line 40

Comment: You need to look for the php class it seems like the ffn definition is missing or something like this.